# What UV intensity (watts per area) should be the maximum a light-skinned person should be exposed to?

Tags: dermatology, uv-rays

I have a UV AB meter that can measure UV A and B light intensity in microWatts/(centimeters squared). In direct afternoon sunlight, I measure UV AB at about 3000 microWatts/cm^2. In the shade of the same afternoon, I measure UV AB at about 600 microwatts/cm^2.

I've been told by dermatologists to avoid being in direct sunlight in the afternoon. So is there a specific limit in  UV intensity (watts/area) where dermatologists would recommend not being exposed to?

Comment: What has your research found so far?

Comment: So far I've found UVA is what I am most concerned about, since it is harder to block and penetrates the skin more deeply. As far as finding an intensity value that has been set as the recommended UV exposure limit, I am having great difficulties uncovering such as value from Google.

Comment: Considering that skin tone makes a big difference I don't think you're going to find a single number.